# jQuery check if list has attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a big list of `li` tags that have the following:

```
<li class="square" data-selected= data-square="1"></li>
<li class="square" data-selected= data-square="2"></li>
<li class="square" data-selected= data-square="3"></li>
```

`onClick` I then add an attribute that's in the `data-square` to the `data-selected` so `onClick` my selected element would look like:

```
<li class="square" data-selected="3" data-square="3"></li>
```

I have 30 of these `li` tags. I basically want to check if any of them have been selected and if so do something.

```
    $('.square').each(function() {
      console.log(count);
      var attrSquare = $('.square').attr('data-selected');

      if (typeof attrSquare !== typeof undefined && attrSquare !== false) {
          console.log('test');
      } else {
        console.log('selected');
      }
    });
```

At the moment, i've placed `console.logs` in to see if i'm getting into where i'm getting in. However, it just spits out 30 test in the window console. I never get into the selected console.
Anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Comment: You should compare `attrSquare` instead of `attrEmoji`

Comment: If reading data you should use `data()` not `attr()`

Comment: lol sorry @Tushar good spot. I had another variable that I was testing with above :) *took it out*

Comment: how are you setting the value of `data-selected`

Comment: `30 test` silly mistake.

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's 200 lines long so couldn't add it in. In short, I do `.each` over some JSON data which gives me back the numbers you see in `data-square`. I then `.each()` over my html elements and append them to the attri

Comment: Yeah, i'm still learning. May not be the best method to be handling data and reading etc. but it's how I got it working and works nicely for what I need :)

Comment: @MeMyselfAndI https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wh30m6rg/1/

Comment: But it will be much more easier if you can add a class also to the `li` if it is selected

Comment: Thanks @Liam I wasn't aware I couldn't read html attributes with `attr()` I needed to use `data()`

Comment: Data is a specialised type of attribute. It's a bit pedantic but really you should always read data using the specialised version. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: @ArunPJohny might be a stupid question. How come in your fiddle you put `return false` what does that exactly do? Is that in replace of having an `ifelse` statement setting the `selected` var back to false?

Comment: @MeMyselfAndI in `.each()` method will stop the iteration if `false` is returned from it... in our case, if we find 1 checked item there is no need to check more elements

Answer (score 2):

You can only target elements that have `data-selected` attribute and then modify its data selected value:

```
$('.square[data-selected]').attr('data-selected',function(){
  return $(this).data('square');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xen3go8r/)**

Comment: `$(this).data('square')`

Comment: Same for `data-selected`

Comment: @Tushar: but that wont reflect in attribute. i guess OP want it as attribute and not data(by looking at o/p markup required)

Answer (score -1):

Please change the jquery code as following :-

```
$('.square').each(function() {
      console.log(count);
      var attrSquare = $(this).attr('data-selected');

      if (typeof attrSquare !== typeof undefined && attrSquare !== false) {
          console.log('test');
      } else {
        console.log('selected');
      }
    });
```

It may help you.

Comment: You **were** unwrapping the jquery object. So that would result in a undefined error. It **now** has the same error that OP has. Basically you haven't addressed the problem. You also haven't said what you've done and why.

Comment: this smells of keep tweaking the syntax in a hope of fixing the issue. Rather than understanding the issue and formulating a solution

Answer (score -1):

find element which have data-selected attribute

```
$('.square[attr="data-selected"]').each(function(){
    // do something.
})
```

Comment: It will look for `.square` elements with an attribute `attr` equals to `data-selected`. And anyway, you aren't answering question